# Elegant syntax for applying a dictionary multiple times

Tags: python

Consider my dictionary `d`:

```
d = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1}
```

This is just a permutation in dictionary form.

How do I reapply this dictionary in a syntactically elegant way?

```
x = 1

# Not Elegant
d[d[d[x]]]

1
```

I want to create a function like:

```
def f(d, k, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        k = d[k]
    return k
```

Comment: If this was an ordered dict you could just walk the key-value pairs no?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your function does the job in 3 short lines doesn't it?

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes it does.... But I'm sitting here wondering if there was a clever way using a `reduce`/`map` type of thing... I couldn't think of one so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea might be to construct a *higher order function* to apply a function *n*. times like:

```
def func_mul(f,n=2):
    def g(x):
        for _ in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return g
```

Another option is to use some kind of `reduce` like:

```
from functools import reduce

def func_mul(f,n=2):
    return lambda x : reduce(lambda xi, _ : f(xi),range(n),x)
```

And then we can write:

```
d3 = func_mul(d.get,3)
d3(x)
```

although I agree that if you need the function only once, this is still *ugly*.

Answer (score 2):

My offhand solution would be to simply create a function, like:

```
def walk(dict, start, iters):
    if iters <= 0:
        return start
    return walk(dict, dict[start], iters-1)
```

Once error handling is added, it will look even less clean, but I don't see a great way to do this robustly while looking much more terse.